# Директива препроцессора  #error

Tags: c++

Какая практическая польза от этой дерективы ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Представьте ситуацию, что Вы написали хитро оптимизированный код для подбора хешей. И он считает, что в байте строго 8 бит. Все рады, все счастливы и хотят запустить Ваш код на "больших машинах" (типа Cray), а на них в байте может быть и [36 бит](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.5). И оно там работает, но как то не так. Ломают голову, дебажат... а все было бы проще, если бы сразу в код вставили проверку и выводили с помощью #error сообщение "а странная у вас платформа, обратитесь к разработчику".

Comment: Тоже вариант.

Answer (score 3):

А вот такая. Предположим, что Вы используете директивы условной компиляции. И среди них есть несовместимые. Тогда в случае их выбора используете директиву #error и программа не соберется (а все равно она корректно работать не будет). Есть еще масса других вариантов использования этой директивы.

Answer (score 0):

Еще пример когда нужно, чтобы был определен или один символ или другой (например или debug или release), но не оба сразу или ни одного.